# Split string on token unless token escaped, but ignoring escaped escape character

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use regular expressions to split an EDIFACT line. In EDIFACT, the components of a line are separated by a token, usually "+". The "+" can be escaped by preceding it with a "?". I can achieve this much using the expression

```
(?<!\?)\+
```

So far so good. However, the escape character itself can be escaped, by doubling it up ("??"). Here are some examples and the output when split

```
ABC+DEF+GHI => ABC, DEF and GHI      (3 elements)
ABC?+DEF+GHI => ABC?+DEF and GHI     (2 elements)
ABC??+DEF+GHI => ABC??, DEF and GHI  (3 elements)
```

It's the third one I'm struggling on. How would I tweak the expression I'm using to behave as required?

Comment: Can be `???`, `????` ?

Comment: You can use [`(?:[^?+]|\?.)+`](https://regex101.com/r/hP7eA6/1) to match the substrings.

Comment: Good point Giorgi, you're right, it should handle repeating escape characters. Wiktor's solution handles this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings that can have escaped entities cannot be split with lookaround-based regexps. Instead, matching is a more reliable approach: match all substrings that are not escaped sequences and not the delimiter, and then those that are.

```
(?:[^?+]|\?.)+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hP7eA6/1)

The `(?:[^?+]|\?.)+` pattern matches 1+ characters other than `?` and `+` or a sequence of a literal `?` followed with any character (but a newline without DOTALL modifier).

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, that looks like exactly what I need. Took me a while to understand is how it is handling repeated escapes. Ie, ABC??+DEF =  2 tokens, ABC???+DEF=1 token, ABC????+DEF=2 tokens, etc, but I see the \?. will swallow any pair of characters starting with a "?". Very nice, thank you